# img css top value changes when changing src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my chess game website [here](http://mateinone.com/?puzzle=8), I have an image of a chess piece (a pawn) that can change after it gets promoted. I position pieces with absolute CSS positioning and give `top/left` values. For some reason, when I change the `src` attribute for a pawn upon promotion, the CSS `top` value gets changed.

In the link I gave, if you solve the puzzle by (spoiler) moving the top white pawn up one square and promote it to a knight, the piece gets moved back to the original square (strangely setting the image's `top` value to 0).

If you look my scripts (source-mapped to `assets/js/mateinone.js`) and place a break-point at line 133, you can modify the `src` value (even via the elements/inspector tab of your developer tools), its `top` value gets changed as well!

Can somebody explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't on line 133, its on line 379 of mateinone.js. The `_setPiece()` method is resetting the original top value to the image. Change your logical so that it doesn't reset it.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot I had an onload there.